# Java Thread seemingly skipping conditional statement

Tags: java, multithreading

For a recent library I'm writing, I wrote a thread which loops indefinitely. In this loop, I start with a conditional statement checking a property on the threaded object. However it seems that whatever initial value the property has, will be what it returns even after being updated.

*Unless* I do some kind of interruption such as `Thread.sleep` or a print statement.

I'm not really sure how to ask the question unfortunately. Otherwise I would be looking in the Java documentation. I have boiled down the code to a minimal example that explains the problem in simple terms.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
    }

    class Test implements Runnable {

        public boolean flag = false;

        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                // try {
                //     Thread.sleep(1);
                // } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                if (this.flag) {
                    System.out.println("True");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public App() {
        Test t = new Test();
        Thread thread = new Thread(t);
        System.out.println("Starting thread");
        thread.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        t.flag = true;
        System.out.println("New flag value: " + t.flag);
    }
}
```

Now, I would presume that after we change the value of the `flag` property on the running thread, we would immediately see the masses of 'True' spitting out to the terminal. However, we don't..

If I un-comment the `Thread.sleep` lines inside the thread loop, the program works as expected and we see the many lines of 'True' being printed after we change the value in the `App` object. As an addition, any print method in place of the `Thread.sleep` also works, but some simple assignment code does not. I assume this is because it is pulled out as un-used code at compile time.

So, my question is really: Why do I have to use some kind of interruption to get the thread to check conditions correctly?

Comment: Use `volatile`. `public volatile boolean flag = false;`

Comment: Try to add the `volatile` keyword to your variable.

Comment: Remember Java multi-threading requires you to pay attention to memory visibility semantics.  Changes to Java fields or other shared memory *may not be visible* to other threads unless some sort of *happens-before* trigger is present, such as `volatile` or the `synchronized` keyword or one of the classes from `java.util.concurrent` is used.

Comment: If you want to know more, *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz is the bible of all things multi-threading for a Java programmer.  Also you should read the [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (start with chapter 17 "Threads and Locks" which is where all the multi-threading is discussed).

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answer, especially to @markspace for the detailed explanation. I'd be happy to mark your response as the answer as it included information as to _why_ that exists and where I can read more into it. However these are comments. Happy to mark you as the answer-er if you write a response!
Thanks again

Comment: @AdamJarvis When Java was designed, there were broadly two choices they could have made: 1) Assume that any object can be modified by any thread at any time and lose an enormous number of valuable optimizations for the 99.8% of the time that doesn't happen. 2) Require code that accesses objects that may be modified by other threads to use some form of indication that this will happen so the optimizations are only disabled in the 0.2% of the time where they need to be. - Sensibly, they chose option 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, my question is really: Why do I have to use some kind of interruption to get the thread to check conditions correctly?

Well you don't *have to*.  There are at least two ways to implement this particular example without using "interruption".

- If you declare `flag` to be `volatile`, then it will work.
- It will also work if you declare `flag` to be `private`, write `synchronized` getter and setter methods, and use those for all accesses.

  ```
  public class App {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          App app = new App();
      }

      class Test implements Runnable {
          private boolean flag = false;

          public synchronized boolean getFlag() {
              return this.flag;
          }

          public synchronized void setFlag(boolean flag) {
              return this.flag = flag;
          }

          public void run() {
              while(true) {
                  if (this.getFlag()) {   // Must use the getter here too!
                      System.out.println("True");
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      public App() {
          Test t = new Test();
          Thread thread = new Thread(t);
          System.out.println("Starting thread");
          thread.start();

          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

          t.setFlag(true);
          System.out.println("New flag value: " + t.getFlag());
  }
  ```

---

But why do you need to do this?

Because unless you use either a `volatile` or `synchronized` (and you use `synchronized` correctly) then one thread is not guaranteed to see memory changes made by another thread.

In your example, the child thread does not see the up-to-date value of `flag`.  (It is not that the conditions themselves are incorrect or "don't work".  They are actually getting stale inputs.  This is "garbage in, garbage out".)

The Java Language Specification sets out precisely the conditions under which one thread is guaranteed to see (previous) writes made by another thread.  This part of the spec is called the Java Memory Model, and it is in [JLS 17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).  There is a more easy to understand explanation in *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz et al.

Note that the unexpected behavior could be due to the JIT deciding to keep the flag in a register.  It could also be that the JIT compiler has decided it does not need force memory cache write-through, etcetera.  (The JIT compiler doesn't want to force write-through on every memory write to every field.  That would be a major performance hit on multi-core systems ... which most modern machines are.)

---

The Java interruption mechanism is yet another way to deal with this.  You don't need any synchronization because the method calls that.  In addition, interruption will work when the thread you are trying to interrupt is currently waiting or blocked on an interruptible operation; e.g. in an `Object::wait` call.

Answer (score 2):

Because the variable is not modified in that thread, the JVM is free to effectively optimize the check away. To force an actual check, use the `volatile` keyword:

```java
public volatile boolean flag = false;
```